# Freemarker Template reading with cfg.getTemplate(path)

Tags: java, freemarker

I am using freemarker Template .
I landup having the bellow issue:

I am keeping a file[test.ftl] in the path `"home/freemarker/test.ftl"`

Bellow is the code i have used to read template

```
Code :
     public Template read_template()
        {
        String template="home/freemarker/test.ftl";//local path

        Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
        cfg.setIncompatibleImprovements(new Version(2, 3, 20));
        cfg.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        cfg.setLocale(Locale.US);
        Template template = cfg.getTemplate(template);
        return template;
    }
```

This workd perfect when i call it from void main()

Now the problem is when i read it while running server.

> Template template = cfg.getTemplate(template);
>   This line throws file not found exception.

Note:

```
String folder_path = RuntimeProperties.get("freemarker.TemplateDirectory");//for server
```

which
I tested reading the same file `test.ftl` with same path using 
just a normal text file reader function of java from server

This was achivable so i confirm there is not path issue .
And the file is availbe in the respective path.

> Error Filenot found Exception
>   cfg.getTemplate(folder_path+"test.ftl");//only with this

Comment: You are using a relative path. This might lead to confusion on the server. Have you considered using an absolute path like "/home/freemarker/test.ftl" to be really sure that the path is the correct one?

Comment: I have mensioned clearly "there is not path issue" as i can use the same path for reading other files  which are succesfull.

Comment: There is a path issue.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't set a `TemplateLoader` in the `Configuration`. As you are using a low `incompatibleImprovements`, your configuration will use the fragile and dangerous legacy default `TemplateLoader`, which uses the current directory as the template root directory.

I don't know how exactly have you "tested reading the same file", but if you have used `RuntimeProperties.get("freemarker.TemplateDirectory")` as the base directory there, then that's where the problem comes from. FreeMarker doesn't use such a thing. (I don't even know what API `RuntimeProperties` is.) Certainly you should have something like this:

```
cfg.setTemplateLoader(
     new FileTemplateLoader(
         RuntimeProperties.get("freemarker.TemplateDirectory")));
```

Also, upgrade FreeMarker in that project. For a while, the error message tells that (a) you are using a deprecated default value and should set the `templateLoader` setting, and (b) from what physical location it tries to load the template from.

(Also, I assume the real code is structured differently, but just in case, note that the `Configuration` should be a singleton, and shouldn't be recreated for each `getTemplate` call.)